# How to test this dependancy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, dependency-injection, tdd

### Background

I am trying to test a simple cache module, but I can't see a way to keep the API unchanged while injecting the dependencies.

### Code

```
const myCache = () => {
    //this is a dependency. 
    //Ideally I would inject it ( a map already created), but if I do it, I will loose connect !
    let map; 

    const connect = url => {
        map = new Map();
       console.log(`This url ${url} exists for illustration purposes only!`);
    };

    const get = key => {
        console.log(`You requested an object with key: ${key}`);
        return map.get(key);
    };


    const set = ( key, value ) => {
        ma.set(key, value);
        console.log(`You want to save value ${value} with key ${key}`);
    };

    return {
        connect,
        get,
        set
    };
};

module.exports.myCache =  myCache;
```

This is a simple cache module using a map, for demonstration purposes.
In this example, I have a variable `map` which is assigned when I call `connect`.

### Problem

The problem here is that I need to know if  the methods `get` and `set` from map are being called with the correct parameters.

Because map is set after running `connect` I can't spy on it ( using sinonjs for example). A possible solution would to be a map already built in into `myCache` but then the API would change which is something I want to avoid.

### Question

How can I test is the methods from `map` are being called with the correct parameters without changing the API of this module?

Comment: If a known dependency is unable to be injected then the dependent code is now tightly coupled to that dependency which makes it rather difficult to swap/mock/stub it out to be able to test the dependent code in isolation. What is the point of not changing the API if the initial API design is bad? If the design is bad fix it now else it will only be worse if you have to fix it later.

Comment: You really should inject map `const myCache = map => {...` instead of tightly coupling to it by creating it manually.

Comment: Ok, let's say I inject map and loose connect. How then do I know map is being created correctly with the right parameters? ( Assuming it had parameters )

Comment: Who is the one in control of the code? not you? I think you need to research 
dependency inversion and inversion of control.

Comment: I am in control. Perhaps you could give an example on how you would fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't see a way to keep the API unchanged while injecting the dependencies.

You don't, normally, keep the API unchanged.  What happens is that you *extend* the API to allow finer control.

```
const connect = url => {
    map = new Map();
   console.log(`This url ${url} exists for illustration purposes only!`);
};
```

To give the client control over the map, we create a new version of the function that accepts a map as an argument

```
const connect_v2 = url, injected_map => {
    map = injected_map;
   console.log(`This url ${url} exists for illustration purposes only!`);
};
```

You can then remove the duplication by having the old map call the new one, without changing its API

```
const connect = url => {
   connect_v2(url, new Map())
};

const connect_v2 = url, injected_map => {
   map = injected_map;
   console.log(`This url ${url} exists for illustration purposes only!`);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a Mock implementation of Map that tracks and spies the created Map objects. This would allow you to check at the end of unit tests what maps were created and what was called on them.